# Simple Oracle Forms Menu

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I wan't to have a simple menu (main menu not menu bar) whith buttons to link to another form(s)/window(s)/caveses(s). Or atleast the code to switch bettween the screen.

[image: preview_of_main_menu]

What code (SQL/PL) would I put in the buttons or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very broad question. If you want to show a specific window on `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` then you can use built in like below-

```
SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('WINDOW_NAME', VISIBLE, PROPERTY_TRUE);  --This would display the window

SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('WINDOW_NAME', VISIBLE, PROPERTY_FALSE);  --This will hide the window
```

The above would work if you use the `SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY` within the same form.

In case you want to call another form from the parent form (which is the case as per your comment screenshot) you need to to use `CALL_FORM` built-in like

```
CALL_FORM('MEMBERS');
```

Comment: This might better describe my problem. A screen shot. http://i.imgur.com/Ydptw.jpg

I might be doing this wrong or maybe an awkward way, I just wanted to getting working whatever the case. Maybe I'm not ment to link to window but rather to canvas or maybe I'm ment to have everything in one form not several.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just make 1 form only?1 form, many datablock,canvas, window

anyway, for your question, just call the block

```
go_block('your_block');
```

if you want to call another block

```
go_block('another_block');
hide_window('1st_open_window');
```

you should make 1 canvas in 1 window for better arrangement

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Stack canvas within the same form which gets visible as you click on the button.

> SHOW_VIEW('CANVAS_NAME');

And in that stack you can do whatever you want.